# how to hide the close button on a kendo modal window

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have a kendo modal window in my angular app.  Sometimes I auto-close the window after a second. At those times, I'd like to hide the Close [x] button, but at other times, not. Can it be done just before the window is opened?

```
    if (autoCloseDelay)        {
        // hide the close [x]  button here ??
        $timeout( function() {
            $scope.modalWindow.close();
        }, autoCloseDelay, $scope);
    }
    $scope.modalWindow.open();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to play with CSS, you can use `setOptions` to set programmatically the actions.

Example for removing the `Close` button:

```
// Get current actions
var actions = $scope.modalWindow.options.actions;
// Remove "Close" button
actions.splice(actions.indexOf("Close"), 1);
// Set the new options
$scope.modalWindow.setOptions({ actions : actions });
```

Comment: Since this approach works "as is" it gets the green check mark. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do it like this:

```
// hide the close [x] button
 $scope.modalWindow.parent().find(".k-window-action").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Here is a sample [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xg5G7/31/)

Comment: Thanks. I can probably adapt this approach, but it isn't exactly the same with the kendo directive for angular.